# How to automate the Google sheet file name based on a specific cell in a certain sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm new to the apps script and appreciate any help you can provide....I have searched extensively and I couldn't find an answer to the below issue.
I have a google sheet file which contains multiple sheets. cell N2 in the first sheet named "cost" with VLOOKUP function which changes based on a different sheets provides the desired file name for example. "Proposal # 24-012-Customer Name-Project Name-Company Name". I would like to use cell N2 value to be the file name. Thank you

Comment: What is your specific  question.  How to automate is not specific.  I don't understand what you want.

Comment: I want the file name to be based on ell N2 located in sheet "cost"

Comment: Could you provide some information on what you have tried so far and why it has not worked?

Comment: I used the below script 
function putcontentsofsheetinfiles() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const incl = ["Sheet1","Sheet2","Sheet3"];
  ss.getSheets().filter(sh => ~incl.indexOf(sh.getName()) ).forEach(sh => {
    let fn = sh.getRange("N2").getValue();
    let files = DriveApp.getFilesByName(fn);
    while (files.hasNext()) {
      let f = files.next();
      f.setContent(JSON.stringify(sh.getDataRange().getValues()).replace(/],/g,'],\n'));
    }
  })
}
and i got the below
Execution log
7:59:57 AM Error Attempted to execute exportSheet, but it was deleted.

Answer (score 0):

I'll take a guess:

```
function putcontentsofsheetinfiles() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const incl = ["Sheet1","Sheet2","Sheet3"];
  ss.getSheets().filter(sh => ~incl.indexOf(sh.getName()) ).forEach(sh => {
    let fn = sh.getRange("N2").getValue();
    let files = DriveApp.getFilesByName(fn);
    while (files.hasNext()) {
      let f = files.next();
      f.setContent(JSON.stringify(sh.getDataRange().getValues()).replace(/],/g,'],\n'));
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me

i get the below error when i debug 
1:07:32 PM Error Attempted to execute renameFile, but could not save.

Syntax error: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list line: 8 file: Code.gs